# Displaying my Http Request get JSON values from my java Class in my JSP page

Tags: java, json, api, jsp

Morning,

I'm New to this, So i was hoping someone could help me or explain where im going wrong, i'm here to learn of course,

I have a class where it actually Gets my Json values from a Http Request and i can see the JSON data, but now i want my Values to Display in my Table in the JSP page, i feel like im missing something huge or something small, perhaps someone will be able to help me?

Here is the Java Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Courses.call_me();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static List<Courses> call_me() throws Exception {
    String url = "https://bmgi.administrateapp.com/api/v2/event/event_prices";
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("jp.pretorius@bmgi.co.za", "Admin*002".toCharArray());
        }
    });
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    StringBuilder response;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
    }

    response.append(response.toString());
    JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
    response.append("result after Reading JSON Response");
    System.out.println("Price Level - " + myResponse.getString("price_level"));
    System.out.println("Event ID  - " + myResponse.getInt("event_id"));
    System.out.println("Region - " + myResponse.getString("region"));
    System.out.println("ID - " + myResponse.getInt("id"));
    System.out.println("Currency - " + myResponse.getString("currency"));
    System.out.println("Price - " + myResponse.getInt("price"));

    List<Courses> CourseList = new ArrayList<>();
    return CourseList;
}
```

> Here is the JSP page

```
                <table  class="table table-hover table-responsive-md table-fixed black-text">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Price Level</th>
                            <th>Event ID</th>
                            <th>Region</th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Currency</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Where in your JSP Page are you pulling the Values from the Java ?? Javascript ? How should this data reach your JSP Page ?

Comment: Hi, Yes like i said im newbie, all this was from research and trial and error, thats the part of the logic i need help with, like what exactly should i do with the JS en jquery or ajax part in calling the class in the jsp, if that makes sense?

Comment: There area many ways to accomplish this, I would recommend you follow some tutorial step by step to get a better understanding. Try [this tutorial](http://www.programming-free.com/2013/03/ajax-fetch-data-from-database-in-jsp.html) to get a little understanding.

Comment: Many Thanks, much appreciated, i'll give it a go :)